# Is it possible to flip the stub of a gt table to the right-hand side?

Tags: r, gt

[image: gt object]

Pictured is the standard layout for a gt table. All I would like to do is flip it such that the stub is now located on the right-hand side and the column labels/table body are swapped to the left-hand side. I've tried like heck to google for the answer, but haven't found anything.

I successfully made this

[image: table]

and would like to essentially "mirror" it like this (you can ignore any text alignment issues, this is a paint creation)

```
example <- structure(list(pos = c("QB", "RB", "WR", "TE", "RB", "DEF"), 
    team = c("PHI", "DAL", "PHI", "PHI", "WAS", "DAL"), name = c("Jalen Hurts", 
    "Tony Pollard", "A.J. Brown", "Dallas Goedert", "Antonio Gibson", 
    " Cowboys"), points = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), division = c("NFC East", 
    "NFC East", "NFC East", "NFC East", "NFC East", "NFC East"
    )), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

[image: this]

Comment: Hi Kent! Welcome to StackOverflow. I added a reproducible dataset for your question :-)

Comment: Appreciate it. I don't think I'd have any problem implementing code suggestions, this is more of a "does this even exist" question.

Comment: it's more for people who would be answering your question !